# ORACLE PL/SQL - Retrieval Issue while using SYSDATE to retrieve a data for a Specific Date

Tags: sql, oracle, scheduled-tasks

Objective : I was not getting the proper data whenever I use SYSDATE to retrieve data for a specific date.

What I have Done so far: I have Created a table with Following Fields
sales_Date | sales_Id | Name | Load_Date

The table contains thousands of records. If i want to see the sales details for a week back. I am using the following query,

```
SELECT TRUNC(sales_Date),SUM(sales_ID) 
FROM sales_DB 
WHERE sales_Date 
BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE-7) AND TRUNC(SYSDATE)
GROUP BY TRUNC(sales_Date)
```

The above query Listing some details in a *list* order(which has sum of _sales_Id_ for 7 days). But,
If I want to retrieve data for a specific date(*let me consider 2 days back*),

```
SELECT TRUNC(sales_Date),SUM(sales_ID) 
FROM sales_DB 
WHERE sales_Date 
BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE-2) AND TRUNC(SYSDATE-1)
GROUP BY TRUNC(sales_Date)
```

the above query Displaying Sum of _sales_Id_ for a specific data which i had Mentioned in the query, In addition to **the data Which Belong to next day**.

in short, If I want to retrieve the sales details which was happened on **day before yesterday**, some data which was **happened on yesterday is getting *overlapped*** whenever I try to retrieve it.

Even we also Tried Number format like
'12-OCT-16 12.00.00.000000 AM'AND'12-OCT-16 11.59.59.999000 PM,

since we are using **Task Scheduling**, we cannot go with the manual retrieval. It has to be scheduled once in a *.bat* file. and the task will gets triggered everyday.

Is there any solutions to avoid these Overlap of data using *sysdate*. or is there any other Alternative method to retrieve the data for a specific date.

Comment: where trunc(sales_date)=trunc(sysdate-1)

Comment: Try `between TRUNC(SYSDATE-2) and TRUNC(SYSDATE-1) - 1/24/60/60`

Comment: What is the datatype of the sales_date column?

Comment: @Boneist **TIMESTAMP** is the data type we have mentioned for sales_Date field.

Comment: @Rene **=** is not yielding the proper result. and that is the reason we have chosen **BETWEEN trunc(sysdate-2) AND trunc(sysdate-1)**

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I really appreciate your answer. we have tried different format instead. it is, between trunc(sysdate -2) and trunc(sysdate-1)-1/86400. so I would like to know, what difference does it makes to define, **trunc(sysdate-1)-1/86400 instead of trunc(sysdate-1)-1/24/60/60**

Comment: Are you seriously asking what is the difference between `x - 1/86400` and `x - 1/24/60/60`? That is basic mathematics! You can also use `x - 1/(24*60*60)` if you prefer.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit ofcourse I knew it is hh:mm:ss(24*60*60).but my question is how does it makes an impact on retrieving the data. like i mentioned in the question, '12-OCT-16 12.00.00.000000 AM'AND'12-OCT-16 11.59.59.999000 PM', in between the time we mentioned right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

between is incusive. Change

```
WHERE sales_Date 
BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE-2) AND TRUNC(SYSDATE-1)
```

to

```
WHERE sales_Date 
>= TRUNC(SYSDATE-2) and sales_Date < TRUNC(SYSDATE-1)
```

Comment: I was just going to post this answer.  I always use the latter statement because it is easy to get hosed with the BETWEEN statement.

Comment: Thank you for your time. we have tried this and it is working properly. We really appreciate your effort. Now we are able to retrieve the exact data without any overlap.